# How extra:Action and Dimensional Pocket work?

Tags: powers, mutants-and-masterminds, mutants-and-masterminds-2e

Dimensional Pocket require two actions (standard/move); one to open the pocket (the standard action) and one to move objects in/out (the move action). The extra:Action decreases one step time it takes to take an action (reaction < free < move < standard < full)

If I apply the Extra action two times what would happen?

1. Affect both at the same time. It becomes (free/reaction)
2. Affect only opening the pocket. It becomes (free/move)
3. You can choose what affect in any combination: (free/move), (move/free) or (standard/reaction)

Label: (Open pocket/move object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you may be acting on a faulty premise. The text of the power, in both the core book and in *Ultimate Power*, states that it's a Move action to move items in and out of the pocket (the same as the general Move action to manipulate objects), and mentions the attack method only in the context of making a melee attack roll (which is generally part of a Standard action). Unfortunately, the example text only covers an "Aura" implementation, and [the only ORQ I could find that sort of addresses it](http://www.atomicthinktank.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=18681&start=0), only covers an idea of a +1 Extra to move items in and out as a free action:

> *If I had this power and I wanted to be able to pull things from it instantly (free action), how would I move the cost down seeing as it is split into the standard action of the attack, and the move action of the "normal" use.
>
>   Is it safe to assume that dimensional pocket that only does items is 1pp per rank and the attack part is the other 1pp per rank?*
>
> **That's essentially how it breaks down, yes. I'd tend to make pulling out objects as a free action a +1 extra for Dimensional Pocket.**

Text from Core book (Italics mine):

> You have a “pocket” dimension capable of holding an amount of material, or even creatures. Your Dimensional Pocket has a 100 lb. capacity at
>   rank 1. Each additional rank moves it one step up the **Time and Value
>   Progression Table**. You can store up to your maximum capacity of items
>   in your pocket, retrieving them at a later time. If you try to fit an item into
>   your pocket that would exceed your capacity, nothing happens. *Moving
>   things into and out of your pocket is a move action*.
>
> You can trap opponents in your dimensional pocket, if you have sufficient
>   capacity to hold them. *Make a melee attack roll*. The target gets a Reflex save
>   to avoid being trapped. A trapped target can use Dimensional Movement to
>   escape. Additionally, the trapped target gets a Will save each round to escape
>   from your pocket with a cumulative +1 bonus for each previous save.

Under that context, I'd say that using the Action extra once could be argued to reduce moving objects in and out down to a Free action, and changing the attack to a Move action. I also think that that's consistent with Steve Kenson's ORQ ruling.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Also, by the ORQ, if I understand it correctly, I not only need just one "extra action", but I can also add a Flaw that only targets items, right? By the way, since I'm quite new at this, is that kind of an official ruling like Sage Advice of D&D?

Comment: Yes. Steve also mentioned that. As regards official answers, Green Ronin's policy is that only the core rulebook and errata are official. Everything else is house rules including official books. And your GM always had the final say. Steve was the system creator, but he also claimed his answers were not strictly official.